# Possible manifold quotients of spheres by finite isometric actions

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, group-actions, quotient-spaces

Suppose I have an isometric action by a finite group on the standard round sphere $S^n$ so that the quotient $S^n/\Gamma$ is a smooth manifold.

First, does this imply that the action is free? I know the converse is true, but it is not clear to me that the quotient being a smooth manifold implies that the action was free.

Second, what are the possible (smooth) quotients? Certainly one sees both $S^n$ (trivial action) and $\mathbb{RP}^n$ ($\mathbb{Z}_2$ action), but are these the only ones?

Comment: Just a few notes: If $n = 2$, the non-free actions of a cyclic group by rotations about an axis give quotients diffeomorphic to a sphere (though the quotient metric has cone points at the poles). If $n \geq 1$, every cyclic group acts freely and isometrically on $S^{2n+1} \subset \mathbf{C}^{n}$ (e.g., by complex scalar multiplication); the quotients are [lens spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_space). In dimension three, there several [quotients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_3-manifold) including the Poincaré homology sphere.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: in what sense are those coney spheres diffeomorphic to $S^2$? Homeomorphic, sure, but the only natural smooth structure I know how to get is that of a smooth orbifold (with nontrivial cone points), no?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis: If I'm not mistaken, the complex $n$th power mapping uniformizes. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: I too wonder what you mean about these coney spheres. Are you saying that they have a smooth structure, though it is not the one arising from the quotient metric?

Comment: In a word, yes: The claim is, because the complex mapping $z \mapsto z^{n}$ extends holomorphically to the sphere, and factors through the quotient of the sphere by the action of the cyclic group of order $n$ acting as rotations about the axis through $0$ and $\infty$, the coney quotient may be identified with the (smooth) image sphere. As you say, with respect to this identification, the quotient metric is not smooth at the fixed points. Whether or not this scheme constitutes a smoothing of the quotient depends on your definitions.

Comment: Well that does answer my question as written. I guess what I really meant to ask was if the orbit space was smooth with the quotient metric, does that imply the action was free. In any case, thank you, your comments are very helpful.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. So I guess the claim that should be true is that $S^n \to S^n / \Gamma$ is a submersion $\implies$ the action is free.