# Is there any relation between subgroupness and induced quotient spaces?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, group-actions, quotient-spaces

Suppose $\Gamma_1\leq \Gamma_2$ are two finite groups, and $M$ a smooth manifold such that $M/\Gamma_i$ is again a smooth manifold.

I want to know

> **Qusetion1:** is there any relation between these two quotient spaces $M/\Gamma_1$ and $M/\Gamma_2$?

AND Is that possible for two distinct finite groups $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2$ (with same order and non-isomorphic or of completely different order and $\Gamma_i\not\leq \Gamma_j$) produce homeomorphic or diffeomorphic quotient spaces $M/\Gamma_1\simeq M/\Gamma_2$? (I work in category of Smooth manifolds.)

In dim=2 I know real projective plane that is $\Bbb Z_2$ action on sphere but I don't know other one. An explicit example may clear the problem to me.

A less-related post without answer: [Possible manifold quotients of spheres by finite isometric actions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2268728/272127)

Comment: For the paragraph beginning "AND", consider cyclic actions on $S^1$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: For example $\Bbb Z_2$ and $\Bbb Z_3$ on $S^1$ both give $S^1$? Ah, you are right, I think dimension 1 is so special because we have only two spaces circle and real line.

Comment: Sure, but by taking products with these examples, you can create examples of any dimension.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: You mean for example $\Bbb Z_3\times \Bbb Z_3$ and $\Bbb Z_3\times \Bbb Z_5$ on $S^1\times S^1$ acting on each factor?

Comment: Yes, or the action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3$ on $M\times S^1$ which are trivial on the first factor.